# Como especificar precisão diferente para valores distintos no python

Tags: python-3.x

Olá, estou tentando imprimir valores com diferentes precisões decimais, mas mesmo após tentativas e pesquisas, não consegui encontrar uma solução.
O trecho do código com esse problema é:

```py
    valor_monetario = round(float(input()), 2)
    moedas = [1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]
    for valor in moedas:
        qtde = int(valor_monetario / valor)
        valor_monetario = valor_monetario % valor
        print('{0} moeda(s) de R$ {0:.2f}'.format(round(qtde), round(valor, 2)))
```

a saída para o valor_monetário = 576.73 é essa:

**1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00**
**1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00**
**0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.00**
**2 moeda(s) de R$ 2.00**
**0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.00**
**3 moeda(s) de R$ 3.00**

mas deveria ser:

**1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00**
**1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50**
**0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25**
**2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10**
**0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05**
**3 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01**

o valor 0.50, por exemplo, é arredondado para 1.00.
Se eu simplesmente imprimir o valor isolado da forma abaixo (que é exatamente como está no print acima, porém de forma isolada), ele exibe o valor com a precisão correta:

```py
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(round(valor, 2)))
```

Como posso imprimir em um único print, valores com precisões diferentes?
Obrigado.

Comment: o que é a variável valor monetário?

Comment: Oi, é um valor de entrada. A saída apresentada tem o valor_monetario com o valor 576.73.

Comment: Fiz a divisão com //, mas deu na mesma @EltonNunes.

Comment: verdade falei rapido de mais, se tiver um tempo pode dar uma olhada na segunda metade deste video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prQ0TGPFFLk&t=2s

Comment: Sem problemas. Vou ver sim. Obrigado, @EltonNunes. Ah a parte da divisão que você sugeriu não interfere na parte onde está dando problema na exibição do valor.

Comment: o seu erro esta no segundo couchetes, vc esta passando zero, deveria ser um

Comment: @EltonNunes , obrigado pela a ajuda, mas o erro não está nesse ponto que você apontou. Se eu passar 1 no lugar do zero, a quantidade de moedas vai aparecer com uma casa decimal, mas a quantidade não deve ter casa decimal após a vírgula. Caso eu faça isso, a saída ficará assim:

`1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00  
0.5 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00  
0.25 moeda(s) de R$ 0.00  
0.1 moeda(s) de R$ 2.00  
0.05 moeda(s) de R$ 0.00  
0.01 moeda(s) de R$ 3.00  
`

ps.: estou mais ou menos na metade do seu vídeo.

Comment: vc tentou o outro couchete?    print('{0} moeda(s) de R$ {1:.2f}'.format(round(qtde), valor))

Comment: @EltonNunes, a solução que você colocou no vídeo deu certinho. Depois eu vi que essa última forma que você comentou também funciona.
Então essas duas formas dão certo (preciso entender melhor como funciona essa questão do format()):

`print('{0} moeda(s) de R$ {1:.2f}'.format(qtde, valor))`

`print('{} moeda(s) de R$ {:.2f}'.format(qtde, valor))`

Muito obrigado pela a ajuda.

Comment: legal que deu certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o valor antes do `:` na expressão de formatação, não é um indicador do valor numérico, antes das casas decimais - e, sim, é qual argumento posicional do `format` vai ser usado - ou seja, a linha:

```
print('{0} moeda(s) de R$ {0:.2f}'.format(round(qtde), round(valor, 2)))
```

vai imprimir duas vezes o primeiro argumento do format, no caso, a expressão `round(qtde)`.

Além de arrumar isso, tem duas coisas que você pode simplificar aí: (1) não precisa chamar o  `round` - a formatação dizendo o número de casas decimais desejadas já arredonda o que você precisar, e, (2), desde a versão 3.6 do Python, não é necessário usar mais o método `.format` - você pode usar as `f-strings`. Com uma f-string, você pode colocar expressões em Python direto dentro da string, dentro das chaves, e antes do  `:` que especifíca a formatação. A sua linha pode ficar simplesmente assim:

```
print(f'{qtde} moeda(s) de R$ {valor:.02f}'
```

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela explicação, @jsbueno.

Answer (score 0):

Obtive a resposta por meio do link enviado pelo @EltonNunes nos comentários.

As seguintes duas formas funcionaram e respondem a minha dúvida:

```py
    print('{0} moeda(s) de R$ {1:.2f}'.format(qtde, valor))
```

```py
    print('{} moeda(s) de R$ {:.2f}'.format(qtde, valor))
```